# How to change the size and color of the number in the ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to give my own size and colors to the numbers in the following plot. Any suggestions please ?

```
cars    country name    number
car1    US  Porsche 1
car2    US  Porsche 0
car3    US  Porsche 0
car4    US  Porsche 0
car5    US  Porsche 0
car6    US  Porsche 0
car1    US  Benz    0
car2    US  Benz    1
car3    US  Benz    0
car4    US  Benz    0
car5    US  Benz    0
car6    US  Benz    1
car1    US  Audi    1
car2    US  Audi    0
car3    US  Audi    0
car4    US  Audi    1
car5    US  Audi    1
car6    US  Audi    0
car1    UK  Porsche 0
car2    UK  Porsche 0
car3    UK  Porsche 1
car4    UK  Porsche 1
car5    UK  Porsche 0
car6    UK  Porsche 1
car1    UK  Benz    0
car2    UK  Benz    0
car3    UK  Benz    0
car4    UK  Benz    0
car5    UK  Benz    1
car6    UK  Benz    1
car1    UK  Audi    1
car2    UK  Audi    1
car3    UK  Audi    1
car4    UK  Audi    0
car5    UK  Audi    1
car6    UK  Audi    1
```

Code:

qplot(name, cars, data=a, size=number, color=name)+facet_grid(.~country)

output

[image]

Comment: You''ll just probably need to `reshape2::melt` your data set...

Comment: or some kind of `tidyr::gather` operation

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @user1883491 It would be better to show the data using `dput` ie. `dput(a)` and copy/paste the output in your post.

Comment: which size and colours are you referring to? the size and colours of the plot points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qplot(name, cars, data=df, size=number, color=name, shape=name)+
    facet_grid(.~country)+
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("gray","blue","pink"))+
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(5,10))+
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(5,6,15))
```

Comment: thanx. how to change change shape as well ?